# replace all weird characters in xml to its equivalent 'character reference'

Tags: php, xml, unicode, character-encoding, simplexml

I have an XML which has some characters like,

```
&pound; &deg;                   /* entity reference aka symbolic character ref */
» & Â • ›                       /* unicode characters */
```

I want to replace both such characters (entity ref & unicode chars) with their "character references" aka "numeric character ref",

```
 &#163;  - character reference for '&pound;' OR '£'
```

How do I implement this? Is there a php function which does this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following works,

1.convert all unicode symbols to entity ref:

eg: `£ to &pound;`

```
<?php
    $xml_str = "One - &amp; Two - &pound;  Three - £";   

    $xml_str = preg_replace_callback('/[\x{80}-\x{10FFFF}]/u', function($match) {
        list($utf8) = $match;
        $entity = mb_convert_encoding($utf8, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
        return $entity;
    }, $xml_str); //One - &amp; Two - &pound;  Three - &pound;
```

2.Now convert entity ref to char ref:

eg: `&pound; to &#163;`

This can be done by using a translation table (ie., an array) and the string translation function ([strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)): [more on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179875/1161412)

```
<?php

 $HTML401NamedToNumeric = array(
        '&nbsp;'     => '&#160;',  # no-break space = non-breaking space, U+00A0 ISOnum
        '&iexcl;'    => '&#161;',  # inverted exclamation mark, U+00A1 ISOnum
        '&cent;'     => '&#162;',  # cent sign, U+00A2 ISOnum
        '&pound;'    => '&#163;',  # pound sign, U+00A3 ISOnum
        '&curren;'   => '&#164;',  # currency sign, U+00A4 ISOnum
        '&yen;'      => '&#165;',  # yen sign = yuan sign, U+00A5 ISOnum
        '&brvbar;'   => '&#166;',  # broken bar = broken vertical bar, U+00A6 ISOnum
        '&sect;'     => '&#167;',  # section sign, U+00A7 ISOnum
        '&uml;'      => '&#168;',  # diaeresis = spacing diaeresis, U+00A8 ISOdia
        '&copy;'     => '&#169;',  # copyright sign, U+00A9 ISOnum
        '&ordf;'     => '&#170;',  # feminine ordinal indicator, U+00AA ISOnum
        '&laquo;'    => '&#171;',  # left-pointing double angle quotation mark = left pointing guillemet, U+00AB ISOnum
        '&not;'      => '&#172;',  # not sign, U+00AC ISOnum
        '&shy;'      => '&#173;',  # soft hyphen = discretionary hyphen, U+00AD ISOnum
        '&reg;'      => '&#174;',  # registered sign = registered trade mark sign, U+00AE ISOnum
        '&macr;'     => '&#175;',  # macron = spacing macron = overline = APL overbar, U+00AF ISOdia
        '&deg;'      => '&#176;',  # degree sign, U+00B0 ISOnum
        '&plusmn;'   => '&#177;',  # plus-minus sign = plus-or-minus sign, U+00B1 ISOnum
        '&sup2;'     => '&#178;',  # superscript two = superscript digit two = squared, U+00B2 ISOnum
        '&sup3;'     => '&#179;',  # superscript three = superscript digit three = cubed, U+00B3 ISOnum
        '&acute;'    => '&#180;',  # acute accent = spacing acute, U+00B4 ISOdia
        '&micro;'    => '&#181;',  # micro sign, U+00B5 ISOnum
        '&para;'     => '&#182;',  # pilcrow sign = paragraph sign, U+00B6 ISOnum
        '&middot;'   => '&#183;',  # middle dot = Georgian comma = Greek middle dot, U+00B7 ISOnum
        '&cedil;'    => '&#184;',  # cedilla = spacing cedilla, U+00B8 ISOdia
        '&sup1;'     => '&#185;',  # superscript one = superscript digit one, U+00B9 ISOnum
        '&ordm;'     => '&#186;',  # masculine ordinal indicator, U+00BA ISOnum
        '&raquo;'    => '&#187;',  # right-pointing double angle quotation mark = right pointing guillemet, U+00BB ISOnum
        '&frac14;'   => '&#188;',  # vulgar fraction one quarter = fraction one quarter, U+00BC ISOnum
        '&frac12;'   => '&#189;',  # vulgar fraction one half = fraction one half, U+00BD ISOnum
        '&frac34;'   => '&#190;',  # vulgar fraction three quarters = fraction three quarters, U+00BE ISOnum
        '&iquest;'   => '&#191;',  # inverted question mark = turned question mark, U+00BF ISOnum
        '&Agrave;'   => '&#192;',  # latin capital letter A with grave = latin capital letter A grave, U+00C0 ISOlat1
        '&Aacute;'   => '&#193;',  # latin capital letter A with acute, U+00C1 ISOlat1
        '&Acirc;'    => '&#194;',  # latin capital letter A with circumflex, U+00C2 ISOlat1
        '&Atilde;'   => '&#195;',  # latin capital letter A with tilde, U+00C3 ISOlat1
        '&Auml;'     => '&#196;',  # latin capital letter A with diaeresis, U+00C4 ISOlat1
        '&Aring;'    => '&#197;',  # latin capital letter A with ring above = latin capital letter A ring, U+00C5 ISOlat1
        '&AElig;'    => '&#198;',  # latin capital letter AE = latin capital ligature AE, U+00C6 ISOlat1
        '&Ccedil;'   => '&#199;',  # latin capital letter C with cedilla, U+00C7 ISOlat1
        '&Egrave;'   => '&#200;',  # latin capital letter E with grave, U+00C8 ISOlat1
        '&Eacute;'   => '&#201;',  # latin capital letter E with acute, U+00C9 ISOlat1
        '&Ecirc;'    => '&#202;',  # latin capital letter E with circumflex, U+00CA ISOlat1
        '&Euml;'     => '&#203;',  # latin capital letter E with diaeresis, U+00CB ISOlat1
        '&Igrave;'   => '&#204;',  # latin capital letter I with grave, U+00CC ISOlat1
        '&Iacute;'   => '&#205;',  # latin capital letter I with acute, U+00CD ISOlat1
        '&Icirc;'    => '&#206;',  # latin capital letter I with circumflex, U+00CE ISOlat1
        '&Iuml;'     => '&#207;',  # latin capital letter I with diaeresis, U+00CF ISOlat1
        '&ETH;'      => '&#208;',  # latin capital letter ETH, U+00D0 ISOlat1
        '&Ntilde;'   => '&#209;',  # latin capital letter N with tilde, U+00D1 ISOlat1
        '&Ograve;'   => '&#210;',  # latin capital letter O with grave, U+00D2 ISOlat1
        '&Oacute;'   => '&#211;',  # latin capital letter O with acute, U+00D3 ISOlat1
        '&Ocirc;'    => '&#212;',  # latin capital letter O with circumflex, U+00D4 ISOlat1
        '&Otilde;'   => '&#213;',  # latin capital letter O with tilde, U+00D5 ISOlat1
        '&Ouml;'     => '&#214;',  # latin capital letter O with diaeresis, U+00D6 ISOlat1
        '&times;'    => '&#215;',  # multiplication sign, U+00D7 ISOnum
        '&Oslash;'   => '&#216;',  # latin capital letter O with stroke = latin capital letter O slash, U+00D8 ISOlat1
        '&Ugrave;'   => '&#217;',  # latin capital letter U with grave, U+00D9 ISOlat1
        '&Uacute;'   => '&#218;',  # latin capital letter U with acute, U+00DA ISOlat1
        '&Ucirc;'    => '&#219;',  # latin capital letter U with circumflex, U+00DB ISOlat1
        '&Uuml;'     => '&#220;',  # latin capital letter U with diaeresis, U+00DC ISOlat1
        '&Yacute;'   => '&#221;',  # latin capital letter Y with acute, U+00DD ISOlat1
        '&THORN;'    => '&#222;',  # latin capital letter THORN, U+00DE ISOlat1
        '&szlig;'    => '&#223;',  # latin small letter sharp s = ess-zed, U+00DF ISOlat1
        '&agrave;'   => '&#224;',  # latin small letter a with grave = latin small letter a grave, U+00E0 ISOlat1
        '&aacute;'   => '&#225;',  # latin small letter a with acute, U+00E1 ISOlat1
        '&acirc;'    => '&#226;',  # latin small letter a with circumflex, U+00E2 ISOlat1
        '&atilde;'   => '&#227;',  # latin small letter a with tilde, U+00E3 ISOlat1
        '&auml;'     => '&#228;',  # latin small letter a with diaeresis, U+00E4 ISOlat1
        '&aring;'    => '&#229;',  # latin small letter a with ring above = latin small letter a ring, U+00E5 ISOlat1
        '&aelig;'    => '&#230;',  # latin small letter ae = latin small ligature ae, U+00E6 ISOlat1
        '&ccedil;'   => '&#231;',  # latin small letter c with cedilla, U+00E7 ISOlat1
        '&egrave;'   => '&#232;',  # latin small letter e with grave, U+00E8 ISOlat1
        '&eacute;'   => '&#233;',  # latin small letter e with acute, U+00E9 ISOlat1
        '&ecirc;'    => '&#234;',  # latin small letter e with circumflex, U+00EA ISOlat1
        '&euml;'     => '&#235;',  # latin small letter e with diaeresis, U+00EB ISOlat1
        '&igrave;'   => '&#236;',  # latin small letter i with grave, U+00EC ISOlat1
        '&iacute;'   => '&#237;',  # latin small letter i with acute, U+00ED ISOlat1
        '&icirc;'    => '&#238;',  # latin small letter i with circumflex, U+00EE ISOlat1
        '&iuml;'     => '&#239;',  # latin small letter i with diaeresis, U+00EF ISOlat1
        '&eth;'      => '&#240;',  # latin small letter eth, U+00F0 ISOlat1
        '&ntilde;'   => '&#241;',  # latin small letter n with tilde, U+00F1 ISOlat1
        '&ograve;'   => '&#242;',  # latin small letter o with grave, U+00F2 ISOlat1
        '&oacute;'   => '&#243;',  # latin small letter o with acute, U+00F3 ISOlat1
        '&ocirc;'    => '&#244;',  # latin small letter o with circumflex, U+00F4 ISOlat1
        '&otilde;'   => '&#245;',  # latin small letter o with tilde, U+00F5 ISOlat1
        '&ouml;'     => '&#246;',  # latin small letter o with diaeresis, U+00F6 ISOlat1
        '&divide;'   => '&#247;',  # division sign, U+00F7 ISOnum
        '&oslash;'   => '&#248;',  # latin small letter o with stroke, = latin small letter o slash, U+00F8 ISOlat1
        '&ugrave;'   => '&#249;',  # latin small letter u with grave, U+00F9 ISOlat1
        '&uacute;'   => '&#250;',  # latin small letter u with acute, U+00FA ISOlat1
        '&ucirc;'    => '&#251;',  # latin small letter u with circumflex, U+00FB ISOlat1
        '&uuml;'     => '&#252;',  # latin small letter u with diaeresis, U+00FC ISOlat1
        '&yacute;'   => '&#253;',  # latin small letter y with acute, U+00FD ISOlat1
        '&thorn;'    => '&#254;',  # latin small letter thorn, U+00FE ISOlat1
        '&yuml;'     => '&#255;',  # latin small letter y with diaeresis, U+00FF ISOlat1
        '&fnof;'     => '&#402;',  # latin small f with hook = function = florin, U+0192 ISOtech
        '&Alpha;'    => '&#913;',  # greek capital letter alpha, U+0391
        '&Beta;'     => '&#914;',  # greek capital letter beta, U+0392
        '&Gamma;'    => '&#915;',  # greek capital letter gamma, U+0393 ISOgrk3
        '&Delta;'    => '&#916;',  # greek capital letter delta, U+0394 ISOgrk3
        '&Epsilon;'  => '&#917;',  # greek capital letter epsilon, U+0395
        '&Zeta;'     => '&#918;',  # greek capital letter zeta, U+0396
        '&Eta;'      => '&#919;',  # greek capital letter eta, U+0397
        '&Theta;'    => '&#920;',  # greek capital letter theta, U+0398 ISOgrk3
        '&Iota;'     => '&#921;',  # greek capital letter iota, U+0399
        '&Kappa;'    => '&#922;',  # greek capital letter kappa, U+039A
        '&Lambda;'   => '&#923;',  # greek capital letter lambda, U+039B ISOgrk3
        '&Mu;'       => '&#924;',  # greek capital letter mu, U+039C
        '&Nu;'       => '&#925;',  # greek capital letter nu, U+039D
        '&Xi;'       => '&#926;',  # greek capital letter xi, U+039E ISOgrk3
        '&Omicron;'  => '&#927;',  # greek capital letter omicron, U+039F
        '&Pi;'       => '&#928;',  # greek capital letter pi, U+03A0 ISOgrk3
        '&Rho;'      => '&#929;',  # greek capital letter rho, U+03A1
        '&Sigma;'    => '&#931;',  # greek capital letter sigma, U+03A3 ISOgrk3
        '&Tau;'      => '&#932;',  # greek capital letter tau, U+03A4
        '&Upsilon;'  => '&#933;',  # greek capital letter upsilon, U+03A5 ISOgrk3
        '&Phi;'      => '&#934;',  # greek capital letter phi, U+03A6 ISOgrk3
        '&Chi;'      => '&#935;',  # greek capital letter chi, U+03A7
        '&Psi;'      => '&#936;',  # greek capital letter psi, U+03A8 ISOgrk3
        '&Omega;'    => '&#937;',  # greek capital letter omega, U+03A9 ISOgrk3
        '&alpha;'    => '&#945;',  # greek small letter alpha, U+03B1 ISOgrk3
        '&beta;'     => '&#946;',  # greek small letter beta, U+03B2 ISOgrk3
        '&gamma;'    => '&#947;',  # greek small letter gamma, U+03B3 ISOgrk3
        '&delta;'    => '&#948;',  # greek small letter delta, U+03B4 ISOgrk3
        '&epsilon;'  => '&#949;',  # greek small letter epsilon, U+03B5 ISOgrk3
        '&zeta;'     => '&#950;',  # greek small letter zeta, U+03B6 ISOgrk3
        '&eta;'      => '&#951;',  # greek small letter eta, U+03B7 ISOgrk3
        '&theta;'    => '&#952;',  # greek small letter theta, U+03B8 ISOgrk3
        '&iota;'     => '&#953;',  # greek small letter iota, U+03B9 ISOgrk3
        '&kappa;'    => '&#954;',  # greek small letter kappa, U+03BA ISOgrk3
        '&lambda;'   => '&#955;',  # greek small letter lambda, U+03BB ISOgrk3
        '&mu;'       => '&#956;',  # greek small letter mu, U+03BC ISOgrk3
        '&nu;'       => '&#957;',  # greek small letter nu, U+03BD ISOgrk3
        '&xi;'       => '&#958;',  # greek small letter xi, U+03BE ISOgrk3
        '&omicron;'  => '&#959;',  # greek small letter omicron, U+03BF NEW
        '&pi;'       => '&#960;',  # greek small letter pi, U+03C0 ISOgrk3
        '&rho;'      => '&#961;',  # greek small letter rho, U+03C1 ISOgrk3
        '&sigmaf;'   => '&#962;',  # greek small letter final sigma, U+03C2 ISOgrk3
        '&sigma;'    => '&#963;',  # greek small letter sigma, U+03C3 ISOgrk3
        '&tau;'      => '&#964;',  # greek small letter tau, U+03C4 ISOgrk3
        '&upsilon;'  => '&#965;',  # greek small letter upsilon, U+03C5 ISOgrk3
        '&phi;'      => '&#966;',  # greek small letter phi, U+03C6 ISOgrk3
        '&chi;'      => '&#967;',  # greek small letter chi, U+03C7 ISOgrk3
        '&psi;'      => '&#968;',  # greek small letter psi, U+03C8 ISOgrk3
        '&omega;'    => '&#969;',  # greek small letter omega, U+03C9 ISOgrk3
        '&thetasym;' => '&#977;',  # greek small letter theta symbol, U+03D1 NEW
        '&upsih;'    => '&#978;',  # greek upsilon with hook symbol, U+03D2 NEW
        '&piv;'      => '&#982;',  # greek pi symbol, U+03D6 ISOgrk3
        '&bull;'     => '&#8226;', # bullet = black small circle, U+2022 ISOpub
        '&hellip;'   => '&#8230;', # horizontal ellipsis = three dot leader, U+2026 ISOpub
        '&prime;'    => '&#8242;', # prime = minutes = feet, U+2032 ISOtech
        '&Prime;'    => '&#8243;', # double prime = seconds = inches, U+2033 ISOtech
        '&oline;'    => '&#8254;', # overline = spacing overscore, U+203E NEW
        '&frasl;'    => '&#8260;', # fraction slash, U+2044 NEW
        '&weierp;'   => '&#8472;', # script capital P = power set = Weierstrass p, U+2118 ISOamso
        '&image;'    => '&#8465;', # blackletter capital I = imaginary part, U+2111 ISOamso
        '&real;'     => '&#8476;', # blackletter capital R = real part symbol, U+211C ISOamso
        '&trade;'    => '&#8482;', # trade mark sign, U+2122 ISOnum
        '&alefsym;'  => '&#8501;', # alef symbol = first transfinite cardinal, U+2135 NEW
        '&larr;'     => '&#8592;', # leftwards arrow, U+2190 ISOnum
        '&uarr;'     => '&#8593;', # upwards arrow, U+2191 ISOnum
        '&rarr;'     => '&#8594;', # rightwards arrow, U+2192 ISOnum
        '&darr;'     => '&#8595;', # downwards arrow, U+2193 ISOnum
        '&harr;'     => '&#8596;', # left right arrow, U+2194 ISOamsa
        '&crarr;'    => '&#8629;', # downwards arrow with corner leftwards = carriage return, U+21B5 NEW
        '&lArr;'     => '&#8656;', # leftwards double arrow, U+21D0 ISOtech
        '&uArr;'     => '&#8657;', # upwards double arrow, U+21D1 ISOamsa
        '&rArr;'     => '&#8658;', # rightwards double arrow, U+21D2 ISOtech
        '&dArr;'     => '&#8659;', # downwards double arrow, U+21D3 ISOamsa
        '&hArr;'     => '&#8660;', # left right double arrow, U+21D4 ISOamsa
        '&forall;'   => '&#8704;', # for all, U+2200 ISOtech
        '&part;'     => '&#8706;', # partial differential, U+2202 ISOtech
        '&exist;'    => '&#8707;', # there exists, U+2203 ISOtech
        '&empty;'    => '&#8709;', # empty set = null set = diameter, U+2205 ISOamso
        '&nabla;'    => '&#8711;', # nabla = backward difference, U+2207 ISOtech
        '&isin;'     => '&#8712;', # element of, U+2208 ISOtech
        '&notin;'    => '&#8713;', # not an element of, U+2209 ISOtech
        '&ni;'       => '&#8715;', # contains as member, U+220B ISOtech
        '&prod;'     => '&#8719;', # n-ary product = product sign, U+220F ISOamsb
        '&sum;'      => '&#8721;', # n-ary sumation, U+2211 ISOamsb
        '&minus;'    => '&#8722;', # minus sign, U+2212 ISOtech
        '&lowast;'   => '&#8727;', # asterisk operator, U+2217 ISOtech
        '&radic;'    => '&#8730;', # square root = radical sign, U+221A ISOtech
        '&prop;'     => '&#8733;', # proportional to, U+221D ISOtech
        '&infin;'    => '&#8734;', # infinity, U+221E ISOtech
        '&ang;'      => '&#8736;', # angle, U+2220 ISOamso
        '&and;'      => '&#8743;', # logical and = wedge, U+2227 ISOtech
        '&or;'       => '&#8744;', # logical or = vee, U+2228 ISOtech
        '&cap;'      => '&#8745;', # intersection = cap, U+2229 ISOtech
        '&cup;'      => '&#8746;', # union = cup, U+222A ISOtech
        '&int;'      => '&#8747;', # integral, U+222B ISOtech
        '&there4;'   => '&#8756;', # therefore, U+2234 ISOtech
        '&sim;'      => '&#8764;', # tilde operator = varies with = similar to, U+223C ISOtech
        '&cong;'     => '&#8773;', # approximately equal to, U+2245 ISOtech
        '&asymp;'    => '&#8776;', # almost equal to = asymptotic to, U+2248 ISOamsr
        '&ne;'       => '&#8800;', # not equal to, U+2260 ISOtech
        '&equiv;'    => '&#8801;', # identical to, U+2261 ISOtech
        '&le;'       => '&#8804;', # less-than or equal to, U+2264 ISOtech
        '&ge;'       => '&#8805;', # greater-than or equal to, U+2265 ISOtech
        '&sub;'      => '&#8834;', # subset of, U+2282 ISOtech
        '&sup;'      => '&#8835;', # superset of, U+2283 ISOtech
        '&nsub;'     => '&#8836;', # not a subset of, U+2284 ISOamsn
        '&sube;'     => '&#8838;', # subset of or equal to, U+2286 ISOtech
        '&supe;'     => '&#8839;', # superset of or equal to, U+2287 ISOtech
        '&oplus;'    => '&#8853;', # circled plus = direct sum, U+2295 ISOamsb
        '&otimes;'   => '&#8855;', # circled times = vector product, U+2297 ISOamsb
        '&perp;'     => '&#8869;', # up tack = orthogonal to = perpendicular, U+22A5 ISOtech
        '&sdot;'     => '&#8901;', # dot operator, U+22C5 ISOamsb
        '&lceil;'    => '&#8968;', # left ceiling = apl upstile, U+2308 ISOamsc
        '&rceil;'    => '&#8969;', # right ceiling, U+2309 ISOamsc
        '&lfloor;'   => '&#8970;', # left floor = apl downstile, U+230A ISOamsc
        '&rfloor;'   => '&#8971;', # right floor, U+230B ISOamsc
        '&lang;'     => '&#9001;', # left-pointing angle bracket = bra, U+2329 ISOtech
        '&rang;'     => '&#9002;', # right-pointing angle bracket = ket, U+232A ISOtech
        '&loz;'      => '&#9674;', # lozenge, U+25CA ISOpub
        '&spades;'   => '&#9824;', # black spade suit, U+2660 ISOpub
        '&clubs;'    => '&#9827;', # black club suit = shamrock, U+2663 ISOpub
        '&hearts;'   => '&#9829;', # black heart suit = valentine, U+2665 ISOpub
        '&diams;'    => '&#9830;', # black diamond suit, U+2666 ISOpub
        '&quot;'     => '&#34;',   # quotation mark = APL quote, U+0022 ISOnum
        '&amp;'      => '&#38;',   # ampersand, U+0026 ISOnum
        '&lt;'       => '&#60;',   # less-than sign, U+003C ISOnum
        '&gt;'       => '&#62;',   # greater-than sign, U+003E ISOnum
        '&OElig;'    => '&#338;',  # latin capital ligature OE, U+0152 ISOlat2
        '&oelig;'    => '&#339;',  # latin small ligature oe, U+0153 ISOlat2
        '&Scaron;'   => '&#352;',  # latin capital letter S with caron, U+0160 ISOlat2
        '&scaron;'   => '&#353;',  # latin small letter s with caron, U+0161 ISOlat2
        '&Yuml;'     => '&#376;',  # latin capital letter Y with diaeresis, U+0178 ISOlat2
        '&circ;'     => '&#710;',  # modifier letter circumflex accent, U+02C6 ISOpub
        '&tilde;'    => '&#732;',  # small tilde, U+02DC ISOdia
        '&ensp;'     => '&#8194;', # en space, U+2002 ISOpub
        '&emsp;'     => '&#8195;', # em space, U+2003 ISOpub
        '&thinsp;'   => '&#8201;', # thin space, U+2009 ISOpub
        '&zwnj;'     => '&#8204;', # zero width non-joiner, U+200C NEW RFC 2070
        '&zwj;'      => '&#8205;', # zero width joiner, U+200D NEW RFC 2070
        '&lrm;'      => '&#8206;', # left-to-right mark, U+200E NEW RFC 2070
        '&rlm;'      => '&#8207;', # right-to-left mark, U+200F NEW RFC 2070
        '&ndash;'    => '&#8211;', # en dash, U+2013 ISOpub
        '&mdash;'    => '&#8212;', # em dash, U+2014 ISOpub
        '&lsquo;'    => '&#8216;', # left single quotation mark, U+2018 ISOnum
        '&rsquo;'    => '&#8217;', # right single quotation mark, U+2019 ISOnum
        '&sbquo;'    => '&#8218;', # single low-9 quotation mark, U+201A NEW
        '&ldquo;'    => '&#8220;', # left double quotation mark, U+201C ISOnum
        '&rdquo;'    => '&#8221;', # right double quotation mark, U+201D ISOnum
        '&bdquo;'    => '&#8222;', # double low-9 quotation mark, U+201E NEW
        '&dagger;'   => '&#8224;', # dagger, U+2020 ISOpub
        '&Dagger;'   => '&#8225;', # double dagger, U+2021 ISOpub
        '&permil;'   => '&#8240;', # per mille sign, U+2030 ISOtech
        '&lsaquo;'   => '&#8249;', # single left-pointing angle quotation mark, U+2039 ISO proposed
        '&rsaquo;'   => '&#8250;', # single right-pointing angle quotation mark, U+203A ISO proposed
        '&euro;'     => '&#8364;', # euro sign, U+20AC NEW
    );

    $xml_str = strtr($xml_str, $HTML401NamedToNumeric);

    echo $xml_str; //One - &#38; Two - &#163; Three - &#163;
```

Now your XML is good to go.